# Restrict User Access on Power BI WITHOUT using RLS but Dax

Tags: powerbi, dax

I need to restrict access users based on their job title and email, without using RLS. My company has G-Suite and our emails are not mapped in Pbix Service.

I tried this way, but it seems it's not working (or it works only with some scorecards and not in charts)

```
var cdv = 
CALCULATE
(   COUNTROWS(table),
    ALL(table),
    table[job_title] IN {"Job Title1", "Job Title2"},
    table[employee_email] = USERPRINCIPALNAME()
)
return IF(cdv = BLANK(),1,0)
```

Could you please help me with it?